# Difference between certificates for APNs

Tags: java, ios, apple-push-notifications

Is it any difference between certificates for development and production servers?

If I have `my_certificate.p12` and for ApnService provide that information

```
 <bean id="apnsServiceFactory" class="org.apache.camel.component.apns.factory.ApnsServiceFactory">
    <property name="feedbackHost" value="feedback.sandbox.push.apple.com" /> 
    <property name="feedbackPort" value="2196" />
    <property name="gatewayHost" value="gateway.sandbox.push.apple.com" />        
    <property name="gatewayPort" value="2195" />
    <property name="certificatePath" value="file:etc/my_certificate.p12" />
    <property name="certificatePassword" value="111" />
</bean>
```

would it be equal with that?

```
<bean id="apnsServiceFactory" class="org.apache.camel.component.apns.factory.ApnsServiceFactory">
    <property name="feedbackHost" value="feedback.push.apple.com" />
    <property name="feedbackPort" value="2196" />
    <property name="gatewayHost" value="gateway.push.apple.com" />
    <property name="gatewayPort" value="2195" />
    <property name="certificatePath" value="file:etc/my_certificate.p12" />
    <property name="certificatePassword" value="111" />
</bean>
```

I mean, will I be able to get some pushes and feedback with only 1 certificate, or I must have both? 
And for test in development, should I use `gateway.sandbox.push.apple.com` or I can use `feedback.push.apple.com` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While you are in development mode, i mean for the builds installed in device via Xcode or OTA, the notifications must use development certificates and need to use `gateway.sandbox.push.apple.com` for sending notifications.

But while in production mode, i mean once you have tested everything looks good, and uploaded build to AppStore/TestFlight. So, for those builds, you required to use production/distribution certificates and required to sent via `feedback.push.apple.com`.

**UPDATE:**

If you required common way for both development and distribution. Then stop using certificates, instead start using token based APNs keys for the same. You can refer more detail about token based APNs keys over here: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/usernotifications/setting_up_a_remote_notification_server/establishing_a_token-based_connection_to_apns

Comment: And how may I distinguish prod/test certificate? I have both with different `teamId` , alias, password, passTypeId for IOS PushService or for PaseTypeId. I can not find any information about does it test or production certificate.

Comment: As you have created it from `developer.apple.com`. So, while creating you have selected, which one you are creating, i mean is it developement one or production one.

Comment: I didn't create that. I got if from a customer. And now I can not test it correctly and find any difference between them :-(

Comment: Not sure about how to differentiate them,normally we give proper names to certificates while creating them.